# How to revert change made by DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, dom

So I made a simple javascript form validator which creates a box with the error message using DOM. But I can't figure out a way how to reset all these changes when i reset the form using 
`<button type="reset">`

I would like to know how it's done please.

Thanks.

**The Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                   function validate(){
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
            var surname = document.getElementById("surname");

            if(fname.value === "" || fname.value === null){ 
                document.getElementById("sbody").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("fname").style.display = "block";               
                return false;   
            }

            //Verify Last Name
            if(surname.value === "" || surname.value === null){
                document.getElementById("sbody").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("surname").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
                   }//End Validate Function
        </script>


        <style type="text/css">
            #sbody{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: #f3f3f3;
                display:none;
            }

            .vis{
                display: none;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="sbody">
            <span id="fner" class="vis">First Name is missing.</span>
            <span id="lner" class="vis">Surame is missing.</span>
        </section>              

        <form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <label for="fname" class="labelStyle">First Name: </label>
            <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value="">

            <label for="surname" class="labelStyle">Surname: </label>
            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" value="">    

            <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will depend upon how you created the boxes in the first place. Without any code we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser cannot magically figure out what has to be done to *reset* the custom changes.

However you can listen to the [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/reset) event of the form using [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ycG6/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="test">
    <div id="errors-ct">The form has errors</div>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
//wait for the DOM to be ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    //store a reference to the errors container div
    var errorsCt = document.getElementById('errors-ct');

    //listen to the reset event of the form
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('reset', function (e) {
        var form = e.target; //this is how you could access the form

        //hide the errors container
        errorsCt.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited my post with the code I wrote. I can't understand how you are implementing it though. Could you use the above example, please?
Thanks

Comment: @SabTheCoder Could you show the implementation of the `validate` function? Your code as is will fail since you are trying to access DOM elements from a script that runs in the head of the document which means none of the elements you are trying to access exists yet.

Comment: @SabTheCoder I added a more complete example while waiting for your response. You should be good to go with what I provided now. You can put the JavaScript part directly in the head like your other script.

Comment: I understood how it works, but I got a question. Are DOMContentLoaded and reset predefined? Other than that I have totally understood it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SabTheCoder What do you mean by predefined? They are part of the DOM spec if that's what you want to know.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot. I managed to implement it in the bigger code and it works perfectly :)

Comment: @SabTheCoder Great! You should always favor `addEventListener` over inline handlers such as `onclick` attributes.

Comment: I'll go and play with this. I started learning javascript some days ago and I'm trying to create and manipulate everything I can. This question you solved makes my possibilities to create stuff seem endless.

Comment: @SabTheCoder If you just started I strongly advise you to start off the right foot ;) Read http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript

Comment: -plalx I started on W3schools, but it's not that great for advanced stuff. The basics are too easy and lack clarity in the explanation. For the past days I've been learning from scratch, trying to build stuff and Googling for hours which help a lot, but as you said, it's better to start off the right foot. I'm bookmarking the link you gave me. If you could send me some other resources, I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the Internet Explorer code? IE 6,7,8,9 and 10 do not support addEventListener. They also do not support DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @jeff `DOMContentLoaded` and `addEventListener` are both supported by IE9+. It's not realistic to provide fully cross-browser examples. The OP can always use jQuery if that'a a concern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the form, as if user hadn't made any selections or added any input, then just set all form element values to their default value, or empty.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/yLMT4/12/)

```
<div>
    <form action="/echo/html" method="get">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="test" data-default="checked" checked="checked"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="reset" value="reset" onclick="resetForm()">reset</button>
        <br/>
    </form>
    <div id="err">Some error message</div>
</div>


window.resetForm = function () {
    var fields = $('input'),
        uname, pass, check;
    uname = $(fields.get(0));
    pass = $(fields.get(1));
    check = $(fields.get(2));
    $("#err").text("");
    uname.val('');
    pass.val('');
    if (check.attr("data-default") == "checked") {
        check.attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        check.removeAttr("checked");
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a great alternative. Thanks for that. I'll try this out :)

Comment: @SabTheCoder I actually do not undertstand this answer much. All the code in `resetForm` other than `$("#err").text("");` seems completely useless since a *reset* button will already reset the form fields to their original value.

Comment: - plalx - Won't it be useful if I actually try to remove the style from the textboxes? Let's say for example, if I forgot to fill a textbox and I click the "Sign Up". Then the error box appears up and the textbox becomes red. Now when I decide to reset the form, The form content will be gone, the error box will be gone, but the style will not. So is it possible to use that to make the styles go?

Comment: The reset will indeed reset the form into its default state. I simply gave that as an example how to get and alter form elements, and reset them into whatever values he needs. And sometimes you create the form empty, and load the default values later from some view model using ajax, and in that case you would want to reset using those loaded values perhaps.

Comment: @SabTheCoder Yes, that would be correct, however this example only reinitialize the values which will already be done by a reset button anyway. However I agree that it at least shows how elements can get manipulated, but I would have chose a different example.

Comment: I added a quick edit to jsFiddle, to show how to remove error styles:

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/yLMT4/16/